# count and group on multiple columns

Tags: sql, database

I am totally new to SQL. I have created following tables..

```
Employee
- employee_id
- employee_name

Projects
- project_id
- project_name

Roles
- role_id
- role_name

Employee_project_role
- employee_id
- project_id
- role_id
```

I have to write a query for: list employees with count of different roles and also list role.
i.e. if an employee(emp1) works as Team Leader(TL) in one project and as Tester(TEST) in other two different projects then the output should be :

```
employee_name   count   Role
---------------------------
  emp1           1      TL
  emp1           2      TEST
```

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
SELECT COUNT(my_table.*), my_table.employee_name, my_table.role 
FROM 
(SELECT r.role_name as role, e.employee_name as employee_name 
FROM employee e 
JOIN employee_project_role epr ON epr.employee_id = e.employee_id 
JOIN roles r ON r.role_id = epr.role_id) my_table
GROUP BY my_table.employee_name, my_table.role;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    E.employee_name,
    count(*) as cnt,
    R.role_name
from Employee_project_role as EPR
    left outer join Employee as E on E.employee_id = EPR.employee_id
    left outer join Roles as R on R.role_id = EPR.role_id
group by E.employee_name, R.role_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping to total up the project sum.

```
SELECT emp.employee_name,count(proj.project_name),role.role_name
FROM employee emp , project proj , role role , employee_project_role main
WHERE emp.employee_id = main.employee_id
AND proj.project_id = main.project_id
AND role.role_id = main.role_id
group by emp.employee_name , role.role_name
```

check it here [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a970c/1)